# Automated EBS snapshots in Windows Server 2003

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-web-services

I've successfully done automatic snapshots from an Ubuntu instance on AWS using a bash script and the API tools. But how is this done with a Windows Server instance? Is there a similar set of tools available?

Comment: As a varian you may use PHP. Please read my explanation here http://serverfault.com/questions/237246/automate-amazon-ebs-snapshot-creation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EC2 API tools on Wndows; here's a [useful link](http://serktools.com/2009/05/19/setting-up-ec2-command-line-tools-on-windows/) with some details.

To replace your bash script, you're better off using a scripting language like Perl or Python that's supported on Windows, or you could look into [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx).