# Automate Amazon EBS Snapshot creation?

Tags: windows-server-2003, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, snapshot

Once in a while I would go to http://aws.amazon.com/console and manually right click my EBS volume and create a snapshot.

This is kind of tedious and I would forget sometimes. Is it possible to automate this actions and say, make a daily or weekly snapshot?

I'm using a Windows Server instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AMI Tools:

- [install AMI Tools](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/setting-up-your-tools.html)
- [create snapshot](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateSnapshot.html)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to command line tools you may use PHP script developed by me. It is easier to setup as you do not need write even a line of code and you do not need to setup environment.

Not only this script create snapshots automatically, it can also delete old snapshots after given period of time.

#### How to setup

1. Open SSH connection to your server.
2. Navigate to folder

   ```
   $ cd /usr/local/
   ```
3. Clon this gist into `ec2` folder

   ```
   $ git clone https://gist.github.com/9738785.git ec2
   ```
4. Go to that folder

   ```
   $ cd ec2
   ```
5. Make `backup.php` executable

   ```
   $ chmod +x backup.php
   ```
6. Open [releases](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases) of the AWS PHP SDK github project and copy URL of `aws.zip` button. Now download it into your server.

   ```
   $ wget https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases/download/2.6.0/aws.zip
   ```
7. Unzip this file into `aws` directory.

   ```
   $ unzip aws.zip -d aws
   ```
8. Edit `backup.php` php file and set all settings in line `5-12`. Pay attention on your region.

   ```
   $dryrun     = FALSE;
   $interval   = '24 hours';
   $keep_for   = '10 Days';
   $volumes    = array('vol-********');
   $api_key    = '*********************';
   $api_secret = '****************************************';
   $ec2_region = 'us-east-1';
   $snap_descr = "Daily backup";
   ```
9. Test it. Run this script

   ```
   $ ./backup.php
   ```

   Check if snapshot is created.
10. If everything is ok just add cronjob. I run it everyday on 23:00. because i use interval `24 hours`. If you setup shorter interval, consider to trigger cronjob more often. You can even set it every 5 minutes. It will create new snapshot only with given interval anyway.

    ```
    * 23 * * * /usr/local/ec2/backup.php
    ```